# c# code to generate shareable download link for files in azure blob

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, blob

I currently have functions that upload files to Azure blob storage and download from it in a Universal Window app which works perfectly well. I am trying to create a process whereby anytime I upload a file to Azure blob, I can create (or return) a shareable download link that I can share with people who can use it to download the files without any need to access the app.

Is this possible?

I have tried using the Google Drive API to do this not minding the fact I have to move my data to Google Drive, but the Google Drive API does not support the Universal Windows App. (And if it does, please let me know how can it be achieved in a Universal Window app.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want anybody (anonymous) to be able to access the Blob - you can put them into a container whose **Public Access Level** is set to **Blob**.

The [documentation here](https://msou.co/be9) shows how to do it through the portal and through code.

Then to share the URI of the Blob, use the `CloudBlob.Uri` property.

Comment: This is exactly what i been looking looking thanks Amit, thanks Matt.

Answer (score 8):

Azure Blob supports something called Shared Access Signature (SAS) which can be generated on a blob or a container to make it available to those who know the SAS token.

It is well documented with code samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)